# With a session store on the server, what does session secret do?

Tags: session, web-applications, rack

I understand if one saves sessions to cookies, you need to encrypt them with a secret else malicious clients could modify their session at will. This design is still bad for many reasons popularly discussed.

However, if one saves sessions on the server (I happen to use a Memcache store via Rack:Session:Dalli) , I understand all the client gets is a cookie with a key the server uses to lookup their session from the store. I still set a session secret. But I don't understand what it does anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypting a large random number results in essentially another large random number.  In other words, if there is no meaning ascribed to the information (its just a random number), then there is no security benefit to encryption.  If the ID you're storing has some information embedded in it, like a certain bit set or only a certain subset of IDs are used, then encryption is useful.

The length of the session ID is important.  Obviously, the longer the ID, the more resistant it is to brute forcing.  The expected number of simultaneous user sessions is also a factor, as the number of sessions reduces the number of brute force attempts needed to find a valid session ID.  For example, two simultaneous sessions reduces the effective strength of the ID by one bit (a 128 bit key becomes as effective as a 127 bit key would be with one session only).  An Amazon-scale website with (say) 1,000,000 simultaneous sessions would effectively lose 20 bits of its session key strength.

If you need to defend against brute force attacks, implement a middleware to check for that.  Adding information to the session id, like an application-unique string, can make detecting a brute-force attack easier (and requires session id encryption).  Note that this does *not* enhance the security of the key itself, and is basically wasted effort unless the app takes some action when presented with an improper session id.

Whatever you do, just make sure to use SSL and set the cookie to https only.  Time out the session server-side, and don't rely on cookie expiration and the good will of the client browser.

**TL;DR**: If only using cookies for session ID storage, encryption is not necessary if a good RNG is used.  Use SSL and set the cookie [secure attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly).

Comment: Ok cool I understand. My session ids increment from 1, so I need to encrypt them so they can't be guessed

Comment: Ah, I assumed you were using a random session ID.  Yeah, definitely encrypt that predictable session cookie.  Preferably with a long, machine-generated key.